# how to add pojo data to $scope model to display data on the webpage?

Tags: java, angularjs, pojo

I have a bean class object and I want to send this bean to angularjs $scope's model so that i can display the data.I tried using Json object but im not able to understand the correct syntax.

This is the controller.StudentsBean is the bean class which contains the data

```
    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
    StudentsService studentsService=new StudentsService();
    List<StudentsBean> studentsBean=studentsService.getStudentsDetails();
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    String json=gson.toJson(studentsBean);
    gson.toJson(studentsBean, pw);
```

This is the angularjs code-

```
.controller("studentsController",function($scope,$http){
$http.get("/AngularJSPrac/students")
     .then(function(response){
         $scope.students=response.data;
     })
```

Im not able to understand how to connect the Java class(Controller) and the Angularjs code.

Comment: Read this article. It will help you. http://javasampleapproach.com/frontend/angular/angularjs-table-display-data-objects-restapis-remote-springboot-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

// java controller  returning list of students

@GetMapping("/AngularJSPrac/students")
    public  List getStudentsDetails() {

```
     StudentsService studentsService=new StudentsService();

     return studentsService.getStudentsDetails();   
}
```

//angulaJS

```
$scope.getstudentList = function () {
    $http.get("/AngularJSPrac/students")
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log("listdata"+JSON.stringify(data));

        })

};
```

try this